# How to choose the right value of k in K Nearest Neighbor

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, knn

I have a dataset with 9448 data points (rows)
Whenever I choose values of K ranging BETWEEN 1 to 10, the accuracy comes out to be 100 percent ( which is an ideal case ofcourse! ) and wierd.

If I choose my K value to be be 100 or above the accuracy decreases gradually (95% to 90%).

How does one choose the value of K? We want a decent accuracy and not hypothetical as 100 percent

Answer (score 1):

Well, a simple approach to select k is sqrt(no. of datapoints). In this case, it will be sqrt(9448) = 97.2 ~ 97. And please keep in mind that It is inappropriate to say which k value suits best without looking at the data. If training samples of similar classes form clusters, then using k value from 1 to 10 will achieve good accuracy. If data is randomly distributed then one cannot say which k value will give the best results. In such cases, you need to find it by performing an empirical analysis.

Comment: So, choosing a square root of the total data points can be the only decision making factor to choose the value of K? Can we get away with that ? @Amjad shibili

Comment: The best way to find out k is by looking at the visualization of your data points. If you still can't figure it out, you can choose the sqrt method.

Comment: Hi @Amjadsibili, this is a clear and simple answer. What is the source (e.g. book, paper, etc.) where you found that wisdom? Thanks!

Comment: hey @richelbilderbeek sorry man it's been around 4 years since I wrote this answer and right now I couldn't even figure out what is this answer is about :( though I guess I got this wisdom from one of the courses I did at Udacity, not pretty sure :/